# ExtJS 3.x: How to disable the red mark indicating a dirty record in ExtJS EditorGridPanel

Tags: extjs, extjs3

EditorGridPanel shows a small red triangular corner on the column that is edited to indicate an unsaved record.

Since I am using autoSave, I don't need to indicate the record as dirty/unsaved.

Is there an easy way to disable this ?

Answer (score 10):

```
view: Ext.grid.GridView({markDirty: false})
```

or

```
viewConfig: {
    markDirty: false
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
.x-grid3-dirty-cell {
  background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: .x-grid-dirty-cell on extjs 4.